# How do you serialize a union field in Avro using Python when attributes match

Tags: python, avro, avro-tools

Say you have this AVDL as a simplified example:

```
@namespace("example.avro")
protocol User {
   record Man {
      int age;
   }

   record Woman {
      int age;
   }

   record User {
      union {
        Man,
        Woman
      } user_info;
   }
}
```

in python you are not able to properly serialize objects stating the type because this syntax is not allowed:

```
{"user_info": {"Woman": {"age": 18}}}
```

and the only object that gets serialized is

```
{"user_info": {"age": 18}}
```

losing all the type information and the `DatumWriter` picking usually the first record that matches the set of fields, in this case a `Man`.

The above problem works perfectly well when using the Java API.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is it possible that serialization and deserialization is not idempotent in Python's Avro implementation?

Comment: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writer.html#using-the-tuple-notation-to-specify-which-branch-of-a-union-to-take

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the standard avro library has no way to specify which schema to use in cases like this. However, [`fastavro`](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro) (an alternative implementation) does have a way to do this. In that implementation, a record can be specified as a tuple where the first value is the schema name and the second value is the actual record data. The record would look like this:

`{"user_info": ("Woman", {"age": 18})}`

Here's and example script:

```
from io import BytesIO
from fastavro import writer

schema = {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "user_info",
        "type": [
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Man",
                "fields": [{
                    "name": "age",
                    "type": "int"
                }]
            },
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Woman",
                "fields": [{
                    "name": "age",
                    "type": "int"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}

records = [{"user_info": ("Woman", {"age": 18})}]

bio = BytesIO()
writer(bio, schema, records)
```